# Execute a function after a native operator called/executed?

Tags: grease-pencil, operator

Is it possible to, lets say, call a custom function after a certain operator is called?

Something like:

```
def custom_func():
    print("Do something here")

bpy.ops.gpencil.layer_add.add_post_function(custom_func)
```

So when I create a new grease pencil layer, `custom_func()` is triggered?